# canDeactivate does not call when clicking on the browser back button twice

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routing

I am facing one issue regarding the browser navigation since a long time. I have tried all the possible solution over the stack-overflow but those solutions are not exactly similar to my requirement.

I have a requirement on **confirm popup message** while navigating or quit the browser app. I have successfully implement the canDeactivate guard but still I am facing some challenges. Here is the example of my code.

```
 canDeactivate() {
    console.log('Route Guard Is Calling');
    if (this.isValueModified) {
      return confirm('You have unsaved changes for Roster Settings. Do you wish to proceed without saving?');
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

but the above code is not working when I already have confirm popup and again I am clicking on the chrome browser back button.

So, I comes up with other solution which is **HostListener**

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  public onPageUnload($event: BeforeUnloadEvent) {
    debugger;
    console.log('Log Host Listner');
    if (this.isValueModified) {
      $event.returnValue = true;
    }
  }
```

But this **hostlistner** work as per my expectation only when I am completely closing the browser tab. 
Please find the **attached screen shot** of my issue for more and better clarification...

[image]